# Jquery append to multi level unordered list

Tags: jquery

I need to append list items to  dynamically. List will looks like this.

```
List 1
    List 2
        List 3
```

I can create one level list using this. But I need to create multiple levels. Can someone guide me to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#parent_cat1" ).change(function() {
        var new_task = $( "#parent_cat1 option:selected" ).text();
        $('#level1').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
    });
});

<div class="tree-content">
    <ul id="level1">

    </ul>
</div>
```

How to add more levels to list using jquery

Comment: first of all provide your html. seconds you could create a JSFiddle. third how do you differ what kind of list you want to add? do you have several buttons for this task? basicly you can just put another ul inside the list item..

Comment: I don't have button clicks. But there are several dropdowns. When user select option from dropdown if thats not the default value I need to add this to list

Comment: you need to provide your html code. and explain when u need a sub-list - e.g. when does an element go into list 3?